# How to Post Using Pastebin API

Tags: api, pastebin

I am attempting to paste something to Pastebin using its API (http://pastebin.com/api). I was wondering if someone could quickly show me the proper format for pasting something (http://pastebin.com/api#2). I am doing this in Java, but that isn't very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since posting the question, I have figured it out and created an API for this. https://github.com/nrubin29/PastebinAPI